# regular expressions with words in different lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
>stat f
-------------- BEGIN of statistic  3 (F)
Activate Context Request Tim
eouts                       :             0
Attach Timeouts             :             0
Deactivate Context Request T
imeouts                     :             0
Detach Timeouts             :             0
GMM_Attach Accepts          :             0
GMM_Attach Completes        :             0
GMM_Attach Congestions      :             0
GMM_Attach Rejects          :             0
GMM_Attach Requests         :             0
GMM_Authentication Failures :             0
GMM_Authentication Requests :             0
GMM_Authentication Responses:             0
GMM_Detach Requests         :             0
GMM_Detach Responses        :             0
GMM_ID Requests             :             0
GMM_ID Responses            :             0
GMM_Protocol Error Unspecifi
ed                          :             0
#more here key:value pairs
--------------  END  of statistic  3
< STAT EXEC'D
```

I want to extract the key value pairs from this string. I have created an "ugly"-looking regular expression:

```
(^\w+\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*:\s*\d+)
```

It just checks for words and whitespaces etc, and works. I would like a more pretty way like: Get me all lines that don't start with `>stat f` or with `-` and don't start with `<`. I tried this

```
(^[^><-].*)
```

but It when a key extends in two lines, then it matches them as two different things. That is i get one match for

```
 Activate Context Request Tim
```

and one for

```
 eouts                       :             0
```

Is there a way to bypass this behavior?

Comment: You need to tell us which language or tool you are using.

Comment: I want to use java but I am currently testing it on here:https://regex101.com/r/lG4sU2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^([^>-][^:]*)\s*:\s*([^:\n]+)
```

As a Java string:

```
 String pattern = "(?m)^([^>-][^:]*)\\s*:\\s*([^:\\n]+)";
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX1xH7/3)

`[^>-]` makes sure we do not capture the line starting with `>`  or `-`. It is also capturing multiline names due to `[^:]` pattern.

A negated character class `[^:]` means *any character (even a newline symbol) that is not `:`*. Since `:` acts as a delimiter, we can match anything before it, and anything after it like that. I am adding `\n` to the 2nd negated character class matching values (e.g. `0`s) to make sure we stop at the newline, as the next line might probably start with the key name.

Output:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work as you say. Some values like Activate Context Request Tim is not mathced.

Comment: I forgot to update the demo, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/iX1xH7/3. I just noticed that you actually want to also match lines starting with `#`, I thought it was a comment.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more the [^:] pattern. I can't quite get it

Comment: A negated character class `[^:]` means *any character (even a newline symbol) that is not `:`*. Since `:` acts as a delimiter, we can match anything before it, and anything after it like that. I am adding `\n` to the 2nd negated character class matching values (e.g. `0`s) to make sure we stop at the newline, as the next line might probably start with the key name. It will also match the last matching line (try removing `--------------  END  of statistic  3
< STAT EXEC'D`)

Comment: Is there anything else you need me to clarify?

Comment: Well I am trying to comprehend it. So you say: We start from the beginning, then we don't want to match > or - so it matches letters and everything even a newline until it hits whitespace. Then the \s* takes place mathces them. : is quite clear, we match the other whitespaces, but then we match everything that is not : or a new line([^:\n]). I didn't get that. Why do u use that instead of simple \d+ since value is always a number. Could that be possible?What troubles me is that since some values expand to two lines, it won't terminate the matching when it reaches the end of line.

Comment: The last sentence of your previous comment should actually be part of the question. If I do not know what kind of values you have, it is difficult to provide a generic solution. So, it means I cannot use `[^:\n]` to capture values, I need to use `[\d\r\n]+` (no idea what linebreaks you are using, thus, I'd add `\r`, too). And `#more here...` should not be caught. Please check https://regex101.com/r/iX1xH7/4